Access the Router only when the internet is not working
Below are the details I see when I am able to connect to the router.
Hardware Version: Archer AX50 v 1.0
Firmware Version: 1.0.9 Build 20200708 rel.55037
Now let me try and explain what is happening. I have 1 router provided by the ISP to which I don't have access, upon the setup from the ISP I provided my own router for the Wifi setup which is the Archer AX 50, they are connected.
When I am using the wifi over a laptop or my phone I cannot connect to 192.168.0.1 at all, but if the signal of the wifi is weak and when I connect to it, it says "connected to the wifi without internet" then I am able to open up 192.168.0.1 without any issues until the Wifi gets access back to the internet. When I open up the tp-link webpage of the router it says 'Internet X' (no connection to the internet). I am not sure why this is happening and I feel its kinda strange.
Next thing is I have installed 'Tether' application on my phone and added the router in question. Few months ago everything was fine and I was able to open up the router from there, right now it says that the router is offline but that does not make sense since I am hooked on the Wifi and I have internet connection.
Looking forward to hearing any suggestions on the case.
